# Maze with constraint on grid

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path

There are some algorithm or solving a simple maze on the web; but what I am trying to solve is a bit more complicated.
Here is an example:

```
####################
#S #D #           #
#  # ##  ##  ###D###
#     #   #   #    #
## #  #   #     ## #
#     ### #####    #
# #   #  D#  #   ###
# ### ### ## # #####
#   #     #       E#
####################
```

S represents the StartPoint; E represents the EndPoint. D(s) are the collecting point. I want to find the all the paths from S to E which go through D. Then I want to distinguish the shortest path.

Here is an example of A* algorithm, How can I assure that paths go through D points.

```
def aStar(self, graph, current, end):
    openList = []
    closedList = []
    path = []

    def retracePath(c):
        path.insert(0,c)
        if c.parent == None:
            return
        retracePath(c.parent)

    openList.append(current)
    while len(openList) is not 0:
        current = min(openList, key=lambda inst:inst.H)
        if current == end:
            return retracePath(current)
        openList.remove(current)
        closedList.append(current)
        for tile in graph[current]:
            if tile not in closedList:
                tile.H = (abs(end.x-tile.x)+abs(end.y-tile.y))*10 
                if tile not in openList:
                    openList.append(tile)
                tile.parent = current
    return path
```

My question is that How i can modify above search algorithm so that it passes through all D points. I want all the paths included D points.

Comment: Blckknght in stackoverflow suggested that: Probably the best approach is to use A* to find the shortest paths from S to each D point and from each D to each other D and to E, then use a separate method to solve the traveling salesman problem using the distances from A*. –  Blckknght

Comment: for that I have to find and sort all D then. Is it correct?

Comment: Crossposted to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26348965/3703627) and [Computer Science SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/31917/9550). Please do not do this: it is against site policy because it fragments answers and wastes people's time when they duplicate contributions that already exist elsewhere.

Comment: The approach from SO sounds reasonable.

Comment: @DavidRicherby sorry I was not aware of that.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The NP-hardness result is for general graphs though - here the graph is planar, and the vertices even sit on a regular grid. This might simplify things considerably.

Comment: @NickAlger Rectilinear TSP is still **NP**-hard so being on a grid doesn't make it any easier.  (If you think about it, you can approximate true straight-line distances arbitrarily closely by a sort of pixellated line in a very fine grid.) It is polynomial-time on trees, though, and most real-life mazes are trees.

Comment: As I read we consider it as a travelling salesman problem which has been merged inside a maze. but still stuck to code it.